# Como validar confirmação de senha no Yup com React

Tags: javascript, react, formulário, validation, yup

Eu tenho que validar um formulário onde o usuário pode atualizar a senha dele, tô usando o Yup para fazer isso.

Meu código tá assim:

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().notRequired().min(3, "O nome deve ter mais de 3 letras"),
  email: Yup.string().email().notRequired(),
  oldPassword: Yup.string().notRequired(),
  password: Yup.string().notRequired().min(6, "A senha deve ter pelo menos 6 caracteres"),
  confirmPassword: Yup.string().notRequired(),
})
```

Preciso comparar dois campos, que são o `password` e o `confirmPassword`. Existe alguma forma no Yup de verificar se esses campos são iguais? Já tentei o `matches()` mas ele só funciona com expressões regulares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo método `oneOf` seguindo o ***exemplo***:

```
validationSchema: Yup.object({
  password: Yup.string().required('Password is required'),
  passwordConfirmation: Yup.string()
     .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
});
```

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Check The Password Confirmation With Yup](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/vahuw4phan-check-the-password-confirmation-with-yup)</sup>

no seu código:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().notRequired().min(3, "O nome deve ter mais de 3 letras"),
  email: Yup.string().email().notRequired(),
  oldPassword: Yup.string().notRequired(),
  password: Yup.string().notRequired().min(6, "A senha deve ter pelo menos 6 caracteres"),
  confirmPassword: Yup.string().
      onOf([Yup.ref('password'), null],'Passwords must match')
})
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [password validation with yup and formik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53576594/6797930)
- [Check The Password Confirmation With Yup](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/vahuw4phan-check-the-password-confirmation-with-yup)

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço isso dessa forma:

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
          name: Yup.string().required('Nome é obrigatório!'),
          email: Yup.string()
            .required('E-mail é obrigatório')
            .email('E-mail inválido'),
          old_password: Yup.string(),
          password: Yup.string().when('old_password', {
            is: (val) => !!val.lenght,
            then: Yup.string().required('Campo obrigatório'),
            otherwise: Yup.string(),
          }),
          password_confirmation: Yup.string()
            .when('old_password', {
              is: (val) => !!val.lenght,
              then: Yup.string().required('Campo obrigatório'),
              otherwise: Yup.string(),
            })
            .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Confirmação incorreta'),
        });
```